# Объекты класса. Как хранить неопределенное количество

Tags: visual-basic

Пишу программу на *visual basic* с одним классом "Человек".

Куда лучше сохранять объекты класса,  если их может быть неограниченное количество?

БД использоваться не будет.

Я так понимаю нужен динамический массив, в каждом элементе которого будет храниться массив с характеристиками объекта. Так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4xaz66w.aspx):

```
Dim list As New List(Of Person)
    list.Add(New Person('Иван'))
    list.Add(New Person('Алексей'))
    list.Add(New Person('Игорь'))
```

Таким образом у вас будет список экземпляров объектов-людей.